# 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for no reason

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrQYA.png)

please help I'm trying to render out a person

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the `+++++` at the beginning. Does it work when you remove the 5 pluses?